# How can I get to the context of an Entity Framework entity from a property setter?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4

Supposed I have an entity framework entity named Foo, and in Foo a property called Bar.

Is there a way in the setter of Bar to get to the entity framework context?

```
public partial class Foo : IObjectWithChangeTracker
{
    public string Bar
    {
        get { /* ... */ }
        set
        {
            // How do I get the entity context here?
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: why would you do that? the context is a dataaccess layer concept, while the entities themselves are a data model concept. is this for a web application? or a client-server application?

Comment: Short answer: Bad data model. Long answer: I need to get to another object in the context that is not directly related to the object, and pull some values from it for the setter. And this is client/server, and I only need this on the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly my approach for doing this would be to add properties to `Bar` that are not under the data contract then write another method that retrieves the other object and set `Bars` properties there. But I may not understand your question for the reasons HighCore stated. The whole idea doesn't make sense to me; an object does not own a context.

```
if (context.OtherObjectTable != null)
        {
            var otherObj = (from obj
                           in context.OtherObjectTable
                           where obj.Name == "Name/key for obj"
                           select obj).FirstOrDefault(); // ensures we only get one back
```

If you're searching by primary key you just remove the `FirstOrDefault()`. If you can get back multiple results create another loop where you iterate over `otherObj` (potentially a list now) and filter on the next identifying property. After that loop you can just do normal assignment like

```
    Bar.Count = (int)otherObj.SomeInt32;
```

Comment: I am fairly new to EF, so I wasn't sure how tightly the entity was tied to the context. It sounds like it is not tightly tied at all. I was hoping, on the server at least, I could get a reference back to the context from the entity.

Comment: @grieve it's not at all. I'll add some code I have in an app that has a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds bad. I don't know how is your application structured, but in the client side (which should have a reference to the Model, you should not have a reference to the Data Access layer (located in the server), nor to System.Data. so you just cannot add code in there referencing to an EF context, without breaking the whole application structure.

I would suggest to add some kind of static delegate to the entity, such as an `Action<Foo> OnBarChanged` and call that in the setter, then in the server side, in some initialization code, set that static delegate to some code where you actually have access to everything you need.

Comment: The client is Silverlight, so I can actually strip out any server specific code with ```#if !SILVERLIGHT...```

Comment: @grieve even worse, you cannot add a reference from a SL project to .Net system.Data.

Comment: I know. I already have to have two separate projects for my current solution. One for the client side, and one for the server side. The both use shortcuts to the common code between them. Messy, but...